# How remove link in VSS 2005

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I want know how to remove the link in VSS 2005.
my case when i was try to make link in one floder file  to another floder file .i miss drop in other folder.i want remove that link.i tryed to remove file from miss droped floder but that file still showing link which deleted.

Comment: Do you mean remove the share link in VSS 2005? If yes, you can highlight the shared file, and then click "Versions -> Branch" to break the link.

Comment: @Windy, you should add your comment as the answer!